# How do I create delta update files to transmit code changesets?

Tags: php, svn, drupal

I'm developing with Drupal, and my production environment is isolated-intranet (No access to outside SVN/etc.)
I can only email files to a person inside the intranet, and they can then update the production instance.

I have been mailing .patch files created on my development environment, the patches are then applied to the production instance.

However using TortoiseSVN on the development, I cannot get the patch files to record all changes in changesets, i.e. File deletions, etc.

Is it possible to make 'delta' files which will contain all the actions, and modifications done to the codebase, and then I can apply it to the production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not limited to SVN in your development environment, git's patches provide that extra info, e.g. file deletions.  You could generate the patch on your development environment using `git format-patch`, mail the file and then `git apply filename.patch` on your production server.  Your production code does not need to be a git repository in order for git apply to work.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to [SVN export just the changed files from tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417960/svn-export-just-the-changed-files-from-tags) but I don't think any of them will handle deletions automatically.  The TortiseSVN method will at least tell you about deletions, though, so you can either write a script for them or have the other op do it manually.

Comment: something similar to what I'm currently doing.. I'm going to try out Kris' solution, and see.