# Extract the key and value from a string separated by pipe using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string which is in pipe separated format as shown below

```
var request = "Country : India|Location : Mumbai|Attachment:Photo.png";
```

When I do a split it gives the following as output

```
var p = request.split("|");

(
"Country : India",
"Location : Mumbai",
"Attachment : Photo.png"
)
```

How do I extract the key and its respective value?
The entire value is in quotes.
Please help

Comment: Before I answer - Your key would be  `Country` and value `India`, right?

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249610/split-a-pipe-delimited-key-value-pair-separated-by-symbol

Answer (score 4):

You could `Array.reduce` on `request.split("|")` and return key value based object.

```
var obj = request.split("|").reduce(function(o, c){
   var arr = c.split(":");
   return o[arr[0].trim()] = arr[1].trim(), o; // comma operator
},{});
```

When you log it by `console.log(obj)`, you get

```
{ Country: "India", Location: "Mumbai", Attachment: "Photo.png" }
```

Comment: Here I am able to get 1st Key and its value i.e Country may be it is just after the quotes, but not the Location and its value.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
function getKeyvalue() {
            var request = "Country : India|Location : Mumbai|Attachment:Photo.png";
            var arr = request.split("|");
            for (var i in arr) {
                var newarr = arr[i].split(":");
                var key = newarr[0]; // key 
                var value = newarr[1]; // value
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code to store all keys in `key` and values in `value`
The key and value can be obtained by using the same index

```
var request = "Country : India|Location : Mumbai|Attachment:Photo.png";

var p = request.split("|");
var key = [];
var value = [];

for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++){
  var pmap = p[i].split(":");
  key = pmap[0];
  value = pmap[1];
}
```

Posting this as an alternative.
Using maps would be a better option.