# Javascript: split key value (with space)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys there is a way to split a string like this:

```
var tMatch='key1="true" key2="Group 1"';
```

in order to obtain "true" and "Group 1"?

I have tried with this:

```
var key1;
var key2;

tMatch.split(' ').forEach(function(x){
        var arr = x.split('=');
        if (arr[1]){
            if (arr[0]=='key1'){
                key1=arr[1];
            }else if (arr[0]=='key2'){
                key2=arr[1];
            }
            }
    });

  alert('key1:'+key1);
  alert('key2:'+key2);
```

But the output for the key2 is wrong , is :

```
"Group
```

instead of

```
"Group 1"
```

because of the space.
Can you please suggest a solution?
Thank you in advance.
Please note that key1 and key2 could contain also multiple spaces like :
key1="Today is a nice day" key2="Tomorrow not"

Comment: Do you want to be able to escape quotes? Then, to do it properly, you need a parser.

Comment: The problem is not the quotes , the part " 1" is missed because of the space, so the output is "Group   instead if "Group 1"

Comment: @MikeC I don't think the solution you suggested works in my case, because also the value of key1 could contain a space or multiple spaces like : key1= "Today is a nice day"

Comment: Could the value of either key contain an escaped `"`? If not, you could solve this using regular expressions, assuming you know the names of the keys upfront.

Comment: @MikeC I don't think it's a duplicate of that. I suspect he wants to split on any spaces that are outside quotes.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but no unfortunately not, what I'm doing is a parser so, I don't know in advance the name of the keys and I cannot add an excape char... :S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a pipe delimited key-value pair separated by '=' symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249610/split-a-pipe-delimited-key-value-pair-separated-by-symbol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't have quotes inside the strings, you can do this using a regexp.

```js
var tMatch = 'key1="false" key2="Group 1"';
var key1;
var key2;

var re = /(\w+)="([^"]*)"/g;
while (match = re.exec(tMatch)) {
  if (match[1] == 'key1') {
    key1 = match[2];
  } else if (match[1] == 'key2') {
    key2 = match[2];
  }
}

alert('key1:' + key1);
alert('key2:' + key2);
```

Comment: Hey Barman! I really like you solution is more elegant of Amit's one... Thanks a lot! (indeed I don't need the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
var tMatch='key1="false" key2="Group 1"';
var key1;
var key2;

tMatch.split('" ').forEach(function(x){
        var arr = x.split('=');
        if (arr[1]){
            if (arr[0]=='key1'){
                 key1=arr[1]+'"';
            }else if (arr[0]=='key2'){
                key2=arr[1];
            }
            }
    });

  alert('key1:'+key1);
  alert('key2:'+key2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
tMatch.replace(/key\d=/g, '').split('"').forEach(function(item){
    if (item.length){
       console.log(item);
    }
```

});